# How is wallet balance over epoch computed to calculate staking rewards?

Tags: staking

Let's say I have two wallets, each delegated to a different stake pool.
At some point within an epoch I transfer some Ada from one wallet to the other.  What will be the applicable balance which is considered staked by each wallet/pool for that epoch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end of epoch `N` the balance in your wallet becomes the staked balance for epoch `N + 2` and the staking rewards for epoch `N + 2` are paid at the start of epoch `N + 4`.

This avoids the need to lock ADA up for staking and also gives the code enough time to do the required calculations before they are needed.

Comment: OK so if I understand correctly, a snapshot approach is used, not an average, and there is also a delay (same delay as per re-delegation).

Comment: Above answer is correct, please accept it. Yes, snapshot of stake is always taken on epoch boundary, and is used for block production epoch after snapshot.